# Unable to run python unittest in debug mode with reference to test folder in VSCODE

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-unittest, vscode-debugger

I recently upgraded my VSCode (1.80.1 from 1.78.X) and all of a sudden I can no longer run the unittests I wrote in debug mode. My Python package has the following structure

```
    myPackage/
    |-- myPackage/
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- example.py
    |   |-- module1/
    |   |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |   |-- ...
    |-- test/
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- test_utils.py
    |   |-- test_example.py
    |   |-- module1/
    |   |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |   |-- ...

    |-- config files...
    |-- README
```

In my tests, test_example.py, I import statements such as:

```
from test.test_utils import magic_function
from myPackage.module1.system import Subsystem
```

This all works fine when I run the test using VScode' s GUI, but when I try to do so using the debug mode it throws the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named test.test_utils`, and when I change the order it becomes `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named myPackage`.

I don't want to hardcode sys.path.append(... ) in every test file, as there are many (100+) and they are still growing. There should be another method, as this code used to work in VSCode 1.78.X. Is there some (new) setting that I should use for the debug mode?

In my workspace folder I have a launch.json and settings.json file. I tried to alter the configuration for debug tests:

old:

```
{
" Version" : 0.2.0",
" configurations": [
  {
    "name": "Debug Unit Test",
    "type": "python",
    "request":"test",
    "justMyCode":false
  }
],
"compounds": []
}
```

The request attribute `"test"` no longer seems valid: changed it to `"launch"` , tried to add a `"cwd"` atribute (`"$(workspacefolder)"`) but to no avail.

Comment: [`request`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_request) has two values that can be set, `launch` and `attach`, but no `test`. Is it useful to add **PYTHONPATH** using `.env` file?

Comment: What a fail to understand is why it works when I run the unittests yet fails when I start them in debug mode. The former implies that the pythonpath is properly set somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can add **PYTHONPATH** using the following two methods:

- Add the `.env` file in the workspace.

  ```
  PYTHONPATH = "path/here"
  ```

  *Note that the file name only has an extension. If it is modified, additional settings are required.*
- Add the following configuration in ***launch.json***

  ```json
              "env": {
                  "PYTHONPATH": "path/here"
              }
  ```

***Both of the above need to execute the script in debug mode.***

Comment: I have included the latter using "PYTHONPATH" : " $(workspaceFolder)", but the debug console still throws the errors " ModuleNotFoundError for my own code.

Comment: Use an absolute path to the folder.